# I am using KivyMD - Python to make fading text animation. I have issues with the animations and possibly the "for" loop function

Tags: python, kivymd

```
Window.size = (350, 600)



kv = '''
MDFloatLayout:
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    MDLabel:
        id: text1
        text: "Hello"
        halign: "center"
        font_name: "BPoppins"
        font_size: "40sp"
        opacity: 1
    MDLabel:
        id: text2
        text: "I'm Percy Black"
        halign: "center"
        font_name: "BPoppins"
        font_size: "40sp"
        opacity: 0
    MDLabel:
        id: text3
        text: "Python Developer"
        halign: "center"
        font_name: "BPoppins"
        font_size: "40sp"
        opacity: 0
    MDLabel:
        id: text4
        text: "."
        halign: "center"
        font_name: "BPoppins"
        font_size: "40sp"
        opacity: 0
'''

class ChangingText(MDApp):


    def on_start(self):
        self.start()

    def start(self, *args):
        # Animate the opacity of each label
        for i in range(1, 5):
            anim = Animation(opacity=0, duration=3)
            anim.start(self.root.ids[f"text{i}"])
        # Call the loop function
        Animation.cancel_all(self.root)
        Animation(opacity=1).start(self.root)

    def loop(self, *args):
        # Create a loop to animate the labels continuously
        for i in range(1, 5):
            anim = Animation(opacity=1, duration=3) + Animation(opacity=0, duration=3)
            anim.start(self.root.ids[f"text{i}"])
        # Schedule the loop function to run again
        Animation.cancel_all(self.root)
        Animation(opacity=0).start(self.root)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChangingText().run()
```

I want the text to fade in and fade out before the next text fades in. My output is either just one text appearing and no other texts later. Or all texts appearing concurrently.

I have tried to play with the opacity value to get these results but none of them are working.

I am sure it might be the loop function. But please have a look and let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.